# Regex to replace image width and height in html content

Tags: php, image, preg-replace, preg-match

Can you please tell me the regular expression to get the width and height of an image and to replace it with a custom width and height?

For example, it should be able to change this:

```
<img src="test.jpg" style="width:1024px; height:600px;" title="test" alt="test">
```

To this:

```
<img src="test.jpg" style="width:600px; height:400px;" title="test" alt="test">
```

Comment: Is this the example input?  or is there other HTML around it?

Comment: Yes, it will come from HTML content...

Answer (score 1):

It's easier and safer to use the PHP DOM model to get at HTML attributes, rather than use a regex.

Comment: yeah but how could we replace the custom width and height using PHP DOM. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP DOM as said. But if you need a regular expression... This works only when `<img>` `style` attribute is written exactly as you reported. Different input can cause unexpected results!!!

```
$width = '320px';
$height = '240px';
$pattern = '/(<img [^>]*style="[^"]*)width:([0-9 ]+px)([^"]*)height:([0-9 ]+px)([^"]*)"/i';
$replace = '$1width:' . $width . '$3height:' . $height . '$5';
$outhtml = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $yourhtml);
```